# Outlook add-in continuously disabled by automatically setting HKCU RegKey to 0 at statup

Tags: c#, outlook-addin

A client of my outlook add-in started complaining that the add-in does not start at Outlook startup. I took a look, and each time that Outlook is started, the LoadBehaviour is set to 0.

- The add-in is written as a managed COM Add-in (sorry, can't change it - legacy tool) with C# 4.0.
- It is registered on HKLM for all users.
- The client is running Outlook 365 ProPlus Version 1708 (build 8431.22.42 click-to-run) 32 bit (16.0.84.31.2110)
- The client machine is Windows 10 64bit.
- The HKCU level LoadBehaviour key that keeps getting reset to 0 is generated on the Software\Microsoft\Office.. node (as opposed to under the Software\Wow6432Node...)
- The add-in appears under the 'Inactive Application Add-ins' list on Outlook but will not enable through the interface (you can set it, but it does not enable).
- Add-in marked as 'always enable' in "slow and disabled COM-add-ins" list.
- This is the only Add-in loading through mscoree.dll listed on the Add-in list (I know if there was another mscoree.dll Add-in and that gets disabled, then ours would be disabled as well).
- I change the HKCU LoadBehaviour to 3 manually through RegEdit, and it loads the Add-in the next time I open Outlook, but on next restart of Outlook the Add-in is disabled and LoadBehaviour set to 0 once more.
- No other client seems to be experiencing the issue, and I am not able to replicate the issue on a local instance of Outlook 365 either.

As always, any help is greatly appreciated!

Cheers!

------EDIT----------

As requested, following is an outline of the actions happening on the OnStartupComplete method of the add-in.

The add-in is meant to provide an Outlook interface for users using the mail-like correspondence exchange component of our larger SaaS service. The add-in connects the user to our server, where they have mail-like items (html formatted) received from other users. The add-in will create a local PST file and create mail items within that PST with the HTML & attachments set as the content. The add-in will also detect if the user is attempting to reply/fwd one of the created 'mails' and override the default process in order to display a web page from the server. The server sync process is triggered at the same frequency as the Outlook Send/receive by adding a handler to the Session.SyncObjects[1].SyncStart event. the sync process itself is handled in a separate BackgroundWorker process.

```
public void OnStartupComplete()
{
    if (_applicationObject == null)
        return;

    try
    {
        if (_applicationObject.ActiveExplorer() == null)
            return;
        _version = _applicationObject.Version.Split(new string[] { "." }, System.StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        StaticGlobals.OutlookVersionString = _applicationObject.Version;
        StaticGlobals.OLIVersion = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version ;
        StaticGlobals.OLIFileVersionString = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location).ProductVersion;

        //This class has all the processes of my add-in process.
        _addinControlObj = new AddInControlerClass();

        //Get references to application, explorer objects
        _addinControlObj.ApplicationObject = _applicationObject;
        _explorers = _addinControlObj.ApplicationObject.Explorers;

        //tracks creation of new explorer & inspector windows in order to override reply/fwd actions on specific scenarios (it provides extra options for the user before opening mail editor)
        _explorers.NewExplorer += this.Open_NewExplorer;
        _currentExplorer = _addinControlObj.ApplicationObject.ActiveExplorer();
        _addinControlObj.ApplicationObject.Inspectors.NewInspector += this.Open_NewInspector;

        //Create redemption object
        _rdoSession = Redemption.RedemptionLoader.new_RDOSession();
        _rdoSession.MAPIOBJECT = _addinControlObj.ApplicationObject.Session.MAPIOBJECT;


        ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ApplicationEvents_11_Event)_applicationObject).Quit += ReleaseComObjects;
        ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ApplicationEvents_11_Event)_applicationObject).ItemSend += SendMail;

    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        Common.HandleErrors(ex, "On Connection", false, null, "", StaticGlobals.OutlookVersionString);
    }


    try
    {
        OutlookCommands olCommands = new OutlookCommands();
        //Get PST file name with Outlook user name suffixed. Common.GetAppPath() will point to a sub folder within either %UserProfile%\AppData\Local or user pre-defined location
        _addinControlObj.FilePath = Path.Combine(Common.GetAppPath(), olCommands.GetFileNameUserSpecific(_addinControlObj.ApplicationObject, "addinCreatedDataFileName.pst"));

        _addinControlObj.CreateProjectConnections(); // connects to the server to retreive access token for API
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        Common.HandleErrors(ex, "On startup complete - Get and validate proj details", true, null, "", StaticGlobals.OutlookVersionString);
    }
    try
    {
        //region create PST store and sub-folders
        _addinControlObj.CheckAndCreateFolders();

    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        Common.HandleErrors(ex, "On startup complete - Check and create folders", true, null, "", StaticGlobals.OutlookVersionString);
    }

    #region add add-in sync method to Outlook send/receive all object
    try
    {
        if (_addinControlObj.ApplicationObject.Session.SyncObjects.Count > 0)
        {
            _syncObject = _addinControlObj.ApplicationObject.Session.SyncObjects[1];
            _syncObject.SyncStart += _syncObject_SyncStart;
        }
        else
        {
            Common.HandleErrors(null, "On startup complete - Warning - No SyncObjects accounts found.", false, null, "", StaticGlobals.OutlookVersionString);
        }
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        Common.HandleErrors(ex, "On startup complete - Add to sync objects", true, null, Properties.Resources.SyncAttachFailMessage, StaticGlobals.OutlookVersionString);
    }
    #endregion

    #region Define the functions for the attachment size limitation.
    try
    {
        _attachmentSizeLimitation.application = _applicationObject;
        _attachmentSizeLimitation.sessionRDO = _rdoSession;
        _attachmentSizeLimitation.connect = this;
        _attachmentSizeLimitation.DefineFunctions();
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        Common.HandleErrors(ex, "On startup complete - Initialize attachment limitation.", false, null, "", StaticGlobals.OutlookVersionString);
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To start off, I don't think anyone can give a direct answer without some code or error. But maybe some extra checks can help you out.

Add-ins are disabled here in the registry, under this node:

> Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\1x.0\Outlook\Resiliency\DisabledItems

(your add-in should not be listed here!)

What might happen is that the add-in crashes while closing.

Sometimes Outlook does not show you a crash/error, to change that behavior this is really helpful:

> Set 'VSTO_SUPPRESSDISPLAYALERTS' with value '0' as a system variable
>   under system > advanced > environment variables,.

https://www.oneplacesolutions.com/support/0053.html

In case the add-in is slow at start-up take a look at, as the Outlook resiliency logic might cause thing behavior.
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/emeamsgdev/2017/08/02/outlooks-slow-add-ins-resiliency-logic-and-how-to-always-enable-slow-add-ins/

Comment: Hi Usselite,
Thank you for your response! I finally got through to the client and did a screenshare with your suggestions.

I have ruled out that the add-in is crashing, as it works when I load it manually.

It is not listed under the Resiliency\DisabledItems node, rather under DoNotDisableAddinList.

Comment: As I mentioned, it is a managed COM-add-in (so the 'location' field shows 'mscoree.dll'), so VSTO_SUPPRESSDISPLAYALERTS would not help.


I know that it is hard to pin-point a non-code issue, and while my assumption is that it is a installation/startup issue, I cannot figure it out and am grateful for any assistance.

Comment: Could you share some of the code? Like what is in the startup? I know from my own experience inbetween Outlook 2016 and Outlook 2019 (after Office 365 update) I had an issue suddenly after a update that I could not attach my add-in to the mailitem. I had to change some behavior in how the ribbon was initialized. Also do you use MAPI in the add-in?

Comment: Hi @usselite, I have updated the OP with the code of my OnStartupComplete. & yes, I do use MAPI but mostly through Redemption. Connections to MailItems are not done in the StartupComplete. And I tested when there were no connections as well (all my methods check if there is a connection defined, otherwise they just return out) and still the add-in was disabled on next startup.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, did you build a installer for the add-in? - Did this behavior start after an update of the add-in? Can the client verify that they don't have two versions (!) installed of the add-in? Looks that you use Outlook Redemption, is that up-to-date? I don't see any specific MAPI interaction within the available code, perhaps try catch all interactions with that.

Comment: The installer is an MSI built with WiX. No, there has not been any updates to the add-in (unless the client re-installed the same version). The last release was in early 2018. Countless other clients are using the same version without issues.

Yes, I have verified that they do not have two versions of the add-in installed. Redemption is no longer up-to date as of now - but it was then. Perhaps I should check that possibility. 

All MAPI interactions are in the sync processes that get triggered later only.

Comment: The author of Outlook Redemption is often active on stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/users/332059/dmitry-streblechenko. Possibly he has an idea.